# Disable pytest logging to original log file

Tags: python, logging, import, pytest

I am calling set_log_path() in a pytest fixture before each unit test, but the logs are now being sent to both the test log file and the original log file.  When running unit tests, I would like to separate these logs so that they do not appear to come from actual execution of the code.

Here is the pytest fixture.

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patch_logs(self, request):
    """
    Log to test dir.
    """
    request.config.pluginmanager.get_plugin("logging-plugin") \
        .set_log_path(os.path.join(get_root_dir(), 'src/test/logs/DS-server.log'))
```

Logs are still appearing in logs/DS-server.log file.  I already tried monkeypatching the function which sets the original log directory, but the loggers are configured on import and hence before the fixture is run.

Answer (score 0):

You should be add the following to your pytest.ini file which will only disable logging to your original directory.

```
[pytest]
addopts = -p no:logging
```

Comment: I just tried adding this and it disabled all logging, including to the test directory.